# Sails is allowing multiple records w/ identical primary keys of type string

Tags: sails.js, waterline

In Sails 0.10, I'm attempting to create a 'user' model that uses the a string (the user name) as the primary key, however Sails/Waterline is allowing the creation of **multiple records with identical primary keys**.

Here's how the primary key is defined:

```
module.exports = {
    autoPK: false,
    attributes: {
        username: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
```

I've only tried this with `sails-disk`.  So, what gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with sails-disk (and by extension sails-memory) in general where it doesn't handle unique indexes on strings; it will work fine in the other supported core adapters (Postgresql, MySQL and MongoDB).

You may run into problems setting `unique: true` on *non-primary-key* string fields for some databases (see [this note in the docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#indexing) and [this answer referring to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870024/sailsjs-waterline-how-do-i-use-a-string-index-in-models-and-associations/25883249#25883249)), but for primary keys there should be no issues.